# How can i call function in submithandler using jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm trying to call ajax function once form validate but it does not work for me. Below jquery `on-submit` method working fine for me.

```
$('#promotionAdd').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        promotionAdd(formData);
        return false;
    }));
```

But I need to call same thing in submithandler which does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#promotionAdd').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                mtitle: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3, 
                }
            },
            messages: {
                mtitle: "Please enter Promotion Title",
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                //alert(this);
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                promotionAdd(formData);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Can any one guide me where i'm wrong and how can i fix it. I would like to appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `submitHandler` `this` refers to the validation plugin, not the form the plugin was called on. Use the `form` parameter that's passed in to the function instead.

Also note that `preventDefault()` will cause an error as `e` is not defined and `return false` will do nothing. They are not required here in any case as the validation plugin handles the prevention of the form submission for you. Try this:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    var formData = new FormData(form); // use 'form' here
    promotionAdd(formData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge with me